# Cakephp logs in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, cakephp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

What is the best way to handle logging with cakePHP in an Elastic Beanstalk environment?
Normally cakePHP writes the logs to the tmp folder of the application. However I see no way to access that folder in an Elastic Beanstalk app.
Am I missing something or is there a specific way to get the logs of your app.

EDIT: The cakePHP Version I'm using is 2.10.9

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the version of CakePHP that you are using so I will assume 3.x

On the official cookbook you can see how to [create a log adapter](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#creating-log-adapters) and you can then use that to push the logs to the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

If you exted the `BaseLog` class as the example suggests you have very little code to write.

Next you need to properly configure your new logger in `app.php`

For CakePHP 2.x you need look at [this documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#creating-and-configuring-log-streams) on how to create a new log stream.

Comment: I'm using version 2.10.9. 
As for your suggestion I cannot see, how this would help me to get the logs out of the Elastic Beanstalk environment. This would just specify a path for the log file in the environment, wouldn't it? The problem is you cannot access the tmp folder within an elastic beanstalk app since it has no ftp to connect to and therefore I see no way to get the data inside the log folder

Comment: I think you did not understand my answer. You do not need to get the logs OUT of the tmp folder. You write a _new_ log addapter in CakePHP that **pushes** the logs into the Elastic Beanstalk environment via whatever connector they have. So, instead of CakePHP writing logs into the /tmp folder it should write the logs directly into the Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: ah. ok sorry my mistake. i'll give it a try

Comment: If that does not work (because you cannot write into the Elastic Beanstalk) then you create a log adapter to write the logs into a *database table*, and maybe you can connect to that table via the Elastic Beanstalk api.